Need help creating a specific sliver scroll behavior
I am trying to implement this scroll behavior:

Or in more detail:

A background image that scrolls with a parallax effect
A small red container that contains a circular logo in a stack-like layout
A persistent header with title and subtitle that sticks to the top of the screen while adding a safe area at the same time (accounting for phone status bar height) once it reaches the top

I tried implementing it with SliverAppBar but there was a lot of issues and couldn't get the same behavior in the GIF. I also tried the sliver_tools package, but it had its own problems as well.

its job for SliverPersistentHeader and the real work has to be done in the delegate's build method

I tried that but couldn’t figure out how to do the logo stacking effect or the size changing to account for safe area

post your code then
